# Jenkins: pass a variable between shell scripts and stages

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to set up a Jenkins pipeline where I fetch the "related" server name with a shell script and store it in a variable ($SERVER), then I want to use that variable in the next stage to login to that server and execute a script remotely.
I came up with the following but can't figure out how to pass the server name between the first and second function:

```
  1 def SERVER
  2 
  3 def fetch_server() {
  4   sh """#!/bin/bash
  5     SERVER = ${env.LOCAL_SCRIPT_PATH}/getServer.sh ${params.HOSTNAME} ${TOKEN}
  6   """
  7 }
  8 def provisioning() {
  9   sh """#!/bin/bash
 10     ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@$SERVER 'bash -s' ${env.REMOTE_SCRIPT_PATH}/script.py
 11   """
 12 }
 13 
 14 pipeline {
 15   agent {
 16     label 'slave1'
 17   } // end agent
 18   environment {
 19     REMOTE_SCRIPT_PATH = '/usr/local/bin/scripts'
 20     LOCAL_SCRIPT_PATH  = './jobs/scripts'
 21   }
 22   parameters {
 23     string(
 24       name: 'HOSTNAME',
 25       defaultValue: '---',
 26       description: 'Enter the hostname of server'
 27     ) // end HOSTNAME parameter
 28   } // end parameters
 29   stages {
 30     stage('Stage 1') {
 31       steps {
 32         withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'some_cred', variable: 'TOKEN')]) {
 33           fetch_server()
 34         } 
 35       } // end steps
 36     } // end Stage 1 
 37     stage('Stage 2') {
 38       steps {
 39         sshagent(credentials : ['username']) {
 40            provisioning()
 41         } // end ssh credentials
 42       } // end steps 
 43     } // end Stage 2
 44   } // end stages
 45   post {
 46     always {
 47       cleanWs()
 48     } // end always
 49   } // end post step
 50 } // end pipeline
~
```

Is it even possible what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: @Cyrus I use bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables that are assigned to in shell scripts don't persist outside of the shell session. You have to get the stdout from the `sh` step and assign it to a Groovy variable like this:

```
@groovy.transform.Field String SERVER = null

def fetch_server() {
  SERVER = sh( returnStdout: true, 
               script: "${env.LOCAL_SCRIPT_PATH}/getServer.sh ${params.HOSTNAME} ${TOKEN}" ).trim()
}
```

Note the use `@groovy.transform.Field` annotation which is required to make the variable accessible from functions (otherwise it will actually be a local variable of the implicit `run` method of the [script class](http://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_script_class)).

Comment: Tnx for the explanation, helped me a lot!